# Recuperar datos de una tabla dinámica con checkbox y actualizar registros

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, tablas

Tengo una tabla que se llena desde una base de datos, se tratan de activos fijos, como computadoras y teléfonos. Mi idea es que cada fila tenga un `checkbox` para marcar cada activo fijo y recuperar su `id`, dado que esta tabla se usará para seleccionar los activos fijo que se irán agregando a un `disposed`, por lo que necesito recuperar el `id` para hacer la correspondiente actualización en la base de datos, pero no logro comprender como almacenar varios valores y posteriormente realizar la instrucción `update` para cada uno. Espero que me puedan ayudar, desde ya gracias.

Esta es la sentencia para la consulta que rellena mi tabla.

```
<?php 
$obj_conexion = mysqli_connect($cons_equipo,$cons_usuario,$cons_contra,$cons_base_datos);
$consulta = "SELECT id_activo_fijo,host_activo_fijo,nombre_categoria,descripcion_activo_fijo,numero_serie_activo_fijo,fecha_compra,inet_activo_fijo FROM activo_fijo INNER JOIN categoria ON activo_fijo_categoria= id_categoria;";
$guardar = $obj_conexion->query($consulta);?>
```

Esta es la estructura de mi tabla.

```
<table id="Table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <input class="busqueda" type="text" disabled>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <input class="busqueda" type="text" placeholder="ID">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <input class="busqueda" type="text" placeholder="INET">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <input class="busqueda" type="text" placeholder="Host">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <input class="busqueda" type="text" placeholder="Categoria">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <input class="busqueda" type="text" placeholder="Descripcion">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <input class="busqueda" type="text" placeholder="Numero de serie">
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <input class="busqueda" type="text" placeholder="Fecha de compra">
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                                while ($row = $guardar->fetch_assoc()) 
                                {
                                 
                             ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="cb_datos">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php 
                                        echo $row['id_activo_fijo'];
                                     ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php 
                                        echo $row['inet_activo_fijo'];
                                     ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php 
                                        echo $row['host_activo_fijo'];
                                     ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php 
                                        echo $row['nombre_categoria'];
                                     ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php 
                                        echo $row['descripcion_activo_fijo'];
                                     ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php 
                                        echo $row['numero_serie_activo_fijo'];
                                     ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php 
                                        echo $row['fecha_compra'];
                                     ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php }  ?>
                        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias guardar los ID en un array y despues recorrer el array con un while haciendo las consultas sql necesarias.
Podrias guiarte de esta pregunta. [Como puedo guardar los datos de un checkbox en un array con llegada de datos limitado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/384733/como-puedo-guardar-los-datos-de-un-checkbox-en-un-array-con-llegada-de-datos-lim)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).